# SwiftUI - grid / table with column headings

Tags: swiftui, vstack, lazyvgrid, lazyhgrid

I'm trying to achieve a design which essentially has the following layout:

[image]

So I need column headings for this table or grid view. The second column does not need a heading.

This seems like a job for a LazyVGrid or LazyHGrid, however I can't seem to find a solution which neatly includes headings like this - it all seems a bit hacky.

Wondering if I am missing a better way to achieve this. I could of course try and create VStacks within HStacks, but this just seems like something which should be accomplished more intelligently than this.

Comment: Welcome to SO - Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to improve, edit and format your questions. 

Without a [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) it is impossible to help you troubleshoot. What have you tried? What part of your code isn't  working. SO is not a code writing service.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just pass the headers into the `LazyVGrid` before you show the content:

```
struct Item: Identifiable {
    let id = UUID()
    var item: String
    var description: String = "This is the item description"
    var quantity: Int = 1
    var price: Double = 0
}


struct ContentView: View {
    
    let data = [
        Item(item: "Image 1", quantity: 2, price: 1.99),
        Item(item: "Image 2", quantity: 1, price: 3.99),
        Item(item: "Image 3", quantity: 5, price: 9.99),
    ]
    
    let columns = [
        GridItem(.flexible(), alignment: .topLeading),
        GridItem(.flexible(minimum: 150), alignment: .topLeading),
        GridItem(.flexible(), alignment: .topLeading),
        GridItem(.flexible(), alignment: .topLeading),
    ]
    
    var body: some View {
        
        LazyVGrid(columns: columns) {
            
            // headers
            Group {
                Text("Item")
                Text("")
                Text("Qty")
                Text("Price")
            }
            .font(.headline)
            
            // content
            ForEach(data) { item in
                Text(item.item)
                Text(item.description)
                Text("\(item.quantity)")
                Text("$\(item.price, specifier: "%.2f")")
            }
        }
        .padding()
    }
}
```

Comment: or just use `Table`